# What indexes would be useful in this query?

Tags: mysql, indexing, date-comparison

I am doing some queries on a large number of records between two tables.  The tables only key are the auto-incremental id's.

```
    SELECT 
    discounts.id,
    vendor_number,
    discounts.sku,
    deal_number,
    deal_start_date,
    deal_end_date,
    sales.cost,
    sales.quantity,
    sales.invoice_date
FROM
    discounts
        INNER JOIN
    sales ON discounts.sku = sales.sku
WHERE
    invoice_date >= deal_start_date
        AND invoice_date <= deal_end_date
```

The work of the query is the date comparisons I am sure, but I am not sure what kind of index to setup to help this query perform better.

Comment: Post the EXPLAIN and proper DDLs

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Just looking for general advice about how to index date comparisons.

Comment: @JasonB They're wanting the statements that created the tables, i.e. `CREATE TABLE discounts ...` and so on.

Comment: This is just a generic version of the actual data, not the actual full table with all the columns etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` condition is really part of the join (assuming that `deal_start_date` and `deal_end_date` are from the `discounts` table).  If so, this is just a `join` optimization.  The best index would have the columns used in the `join`, `sku` first (because of the equality).  So, I think these would be good indexes:

```
sales(sku, invoice_date)
discounts(sku, deal_start_date, deal_end_date)
```